# What is the elastic search query filter highest score

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search, I am curious to know what is the highest query filter score in elastic search, means what is the maximum limit, is the max. value 100 or 10 or 1000.

Or there is no limit, it depends upon lucene function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is based on the scoring logic,

```
score(q,d) = 
   queryNorm(q) 
  * coord(q,d) 
  * SUM ( 
        tf(t in d), 
        idf(t)², 
        t.getBoost(), 
        norm(t,d) 
                ) (t in q)
```

i got this from https://www.compose.com/articles/how-scoring-works-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: Yes, Even I think the same... but how it normalized as this  is the step after the Boolean function....